# Unity Editor Installation Error

Tags: lubuntu, programming, unity3d

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04.2 and I want to install Unity Editor from the official Unity Hub 2.4.3 downloaded from the official Unity website. But When I try to install the latest Unity Editor LTS, It keeps saying "Not enough disk space to installing Unity.". But I have activated the license and there is still 103GB of free disk space. The installation requirement is 20GB. It is enough for installing it. Can you help me? The unity version I want to install is 2020.3.7.f1.

Comment: Providing the actual error (esp. if from command, what is your $PWD for example; we'd likely know if we could see the command you executed) and what is your partitioning scheme?  If you've subdivided your space across multiple partitions; you may have space in other locations but not where you're trying to install it. More specific details may help.

Comment: I'm running the UnityHub from `./UnityHub.AppImage` in terminal and from [Unity3D Download](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download) and I could install the editor without any problem on ubuntu 20.10. And I'm not talking about installing to another partition. The installation destination is `/home/kenryu/Unity`. The disk I'm using is 128GB SSD. And the partition structure is only one 117GiB ext4 partition mounted as `/`.

Comment: The "./" is a *relative* address thus the $PWD is unknown.  Please provide additional details in your question (and don't reply via comment unless it contains no additional detail). How are you specifying the destination directory?  ie. command (including prompt which by default shows your $PWD) is thus helpful  (if you've changed your $PS1 we'll ask for the additional detail..)

Comment: The AppImage is in `/opt/UnityHub.Appimage` I set the installation destination in UnityHub initial general settings.